# Changing filegroups from primary to user-defined for existing table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 10 million records in a table. But the table is created on primary filegroup.All the indexes and primary keys were created in primary filegroup.There 5 partitions on the table which are also on Primary File group. Is there any way to move Table, indexes and primary key and partitions to user-defined filegroup Without loosing or changing the data in the table?

Comment: There's a pretty good tutorial from Dan Guzman here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/04/17/move-a-partition-to-a-different-file-group-efficiently.aspx